# Automatically join the user who created the group

Tags: python, django

I have a project called social clone project in this project you can only post if you are in a group. What i want to happen is if the user created a group the user should automatically in the group, in this case if i created a group i still need to join the group to join my own group. I tried to search this on google but i get no result and i hope someone will help me and btw i'm just new here in programming and i'm currently learning django.

models.py

```
##########################
## GROUPS VIEWS.PY FILE ##
##########################

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django import template
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from misaka import html
from django.urls import reverse

User = get_user_model()
register = template.Library()

class Group(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    description_html = models.TextField(editable=False, blank=True, default="")
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='GroupMember')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.description_html = html(self.description)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class GroupMember(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_groups', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='memberships', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:

        unique_together = ('user', 'group')
```

views.py

```
##########################
## GROUPS VIEWS.PY FILE ##
##########################

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views import generic
from groups.models import Group, GroupMember
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib import messages

class CreateGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):

    model = Group
    fields = ('name', 'description')

class SingleGroup(generic.DetailView):
    model = Group

class ListGroups(generic.ListView):
    model = Group

class JoinGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'slug': self.kwargs.get('slug')})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        group = get_object_or_404(Group, slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))

        try:
            GroupMember.objects.create(user=self.request.user, group=group)
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.warning(self.request, (f"Warning, already a group member of {group.name} group."))
        else:
            messages.success(self.request, (f"You are now a member of {group.name} Group."))

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

class LeaveGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'slug': self.kwargs.get('slug')})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            membership = GroupMember.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user,
                group__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')
            ).get()
        except GroupMember.DoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, ("You can't leave this group because you aren't in it!"))
        else:
            membership.delete()
            messages.success(self.request, ("You have successfully left this group."))

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

group_form.html

```
{% extends 'groups/group_base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

    {% block group_content %}
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Create New Group</h4>

            <form id="groupForm" action="{% url 'groups:create' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% bootstrap_form form %}
                {% buttons %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Create</button>
                {% endbuttons %}
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

group_detail.html

```
{% extends 'groups/group_base.html' %}

    {% block pregroup %}
        <div class="container">
            <h1>{{ group.name }}</h1>
            <h2>Member Count: {{ group.members.count }}</h2>

            <div class="content">
                {% if user in group.members.all %}
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" href="{% url 'groups:leave' slug=group.slug %}"><span class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></span>Leave</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" href="{% url 'groups:join' slug=group.slug %}"><span class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></span>Join</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block group_content %}
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {% if group.posts.count == 0 %}
                <h2>No Post In This Group Yet!</h2>
            {% else %}
                {% for post in group.posts.all %}
                    {% include 'posts/_post.html' %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override the `form_valid` method on your `CreateGroup` view, here you can perform some additional logic after the object has been saved

```
class CreateGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):

    model = Group
    fields = ('name', 'description')

    def form_valid(self, form):
       result = super().form_valid(form)
       GroupMember.objects.create(user=self.request.user, group=self.object)
       return result
```

[ccbv.co.uk](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#form_valid) is fantastic for inspecting the available methods there are to override for the built-in class based views